# symfony route seems to work with GET but not POST

Tags: symfony1

I have a page whose URI is `/importBundle/96/iTunes` where `96` is the import bundle's id. When I navigate to this page in a browser, it works just fine. However, when I submit the form (which submits right back to the same page) I get "Action "importBundle/96" does not exist," which is absolutely true, but that's not where I'm telling it to go. When I get this error, I still see `/importBundle/96/iTunes` in the address bar.

Any idea why this could be the case?

(I'm on symfony 1.4.)

**Edit**: here's what I have in my routing.yml:

```
import_bundle:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                ImportBundle
    module:               importBundle
    prefix_path:          /importBundle
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
```

And here's my opening `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('importBundle/iTunes?id='.$import_bundle->getId()) ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Edit 2**: Here's how I tried to add `sf_method`:

```
import_bundle:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                ImportBundle
    module:               importBundle
    prefix_path:          /importBundle
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get,post]
```

It doesn't work. Did I do it wrong? The way I did it seems consistent with [the docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05#chapter_05_route_class), so I'm confused.

Comment: Could you show us the corresponding entry of your routing.yml file?

Comment: Also, could you include the action="" part of the <form> that you're submitting.

Comment: I added those things; see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just creating a whole new routing rule just for this one page. Not a very cool thing to have to do but it works.

```
import_bundle_itunes:
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  url:     /iTunes/:id
  options: { model: ImportBundle, type: object }
  param:   { module: importBundle, action: iTunes }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [get,post]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably submitting a form with post method, and the route in question is only configured for get method. Then, symfony falls back to default /:module/:action/* route and obviously can't find "importBundle/96".

If you post to the same page, then the url should be configured both for get and post methods.

```
url_name:
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get,post]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the sfRequestRoute class. See the accepted answer in [Configuring a route in Symfony with the same URL but different HTTP methods and controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875878/configuring-a-route-in-symfony-with-the-same-url-but-different-http-methods-and/8038371#8038371)